# Set fragment ID on load without triggering onhashchange event

Tags: javascript, html

I just wondered if there's a way to change the fragment ID of the main page when it loads up (i.e www.test.com becomes www.test.com/#index) without triggering a hashchange event.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Nope, that would be considered a hashchange, plain and simple. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm dynamically loading content based on the fragment ID. My anchors have #1, #2 etc as the href and when the hash changes, content is loaded. When my index loaded, I had it set to change the hash in the body onload function so that it loads the main content. Problem is, pagespeed was whinging that none of my content could be loaded without loading the external stuff. So I moved it internal. Now when you load the page, there isn't an ID to start with, so when I click a link, it loads the relevant stuff, but when I click back, the fragment ID disappears so it doesn't reload the initial content.

Comment: And cheers Diodeus ;) the character limit didn't leave me any room for manners there!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from having the server spit out the page with the hash, the only thing I can suggest you try is putting an inline JavaScript block, high up in your `<head>` section, which will block the loading of the script tags below. So you should be able to set the hash before the rest of your external scripts load.

Comment: What I've ended up doing is thinking "sod pagespeed" and having the index content separate again. This caused another problem which I hadn't noticed before. If someone wanted to go straight to a link on my site (say test.com/#pictures) the onload function would still change the hash to #index and load the main content instead of the link. To get around that, I've removed the onload hashchange and told it to check what the hash is instead. If it's empty, I tell it to load the index, if it isn't, it loads the relevant content. All this is only because I was trying to keep pagespeed happy!